# foreign key prevents deletion of data in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database

I'm designing a website of book library for my project in php.

Anyways I have three tables named `books`,`users` and `savebook`.

Table `book` has following columns: "`bookid`", "`title`","`author`" "`genre`" and "`summary`".

And table `users` has following columns `userid`, `username`, `password`, and `name`.

Users can save books as favorites and those saved books are saved in the table named `savebook` with columns `bookid` and `userid` which are foreign key to table `book` and `users`

I used following query for that:

```
ALTER TABLE savebook
ADD CONSTRAINT bkid_usid
FOREIGN KEY (bookid)
REFERENCES books (bookid);
```

and

```
ALTER TABLE savebook
ADD CONSTRAINT usid_bkid
FOREIGN KEY (userid)
REFERENCES users(userid);
```

Now the problem is whenever i try to delete a book from table `book` using query

```
DELETE FROM books
WHERE bookid=1;
```

I get this message:

> 1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`booklibrary`.`savebook`, CONSTRAINT `bkid_usid` FOREIGN KEY (`bookid`) REFERENCES `books` (`bookid`))

How do i delete a book from table `book` which also deletes the related row in table `savebook`?

Answer (score 4):

To get the behavior you describe, you can specify

```
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

as part of the foreign key definition.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

If you were to modify your foreign key constraint `bkid_usid` (on the `booksave` table), then the delete statement that you show

```
DELETE FROM books WHERE ...
```

Would cause MySQL to delete the rows in `booksave` that have a foreign key values that reference rows being removed from `books`.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE savebook
ADD CONSTRAINT bkid_usid
FOREIGN KEY (bookid)
REFERENCES books (bookid)
ON DELETE CASCADE
;
```

Make note of that last line I added to the ALTER from the original question, it is an optional part of the foreign key definition (there is also `ON UPDATE` ...). By default, when not specified, I believe MySQL treats it as `NO ACTION` or `RESTRICT` (those two are effectively the same as far as I know) instead of `CASCADE`. Full documentation found at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: Why should the OP try this? Please add an explanation (it makes a better answer and may gain you IIP's) of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, he had it almost right, I figured the one extra line was self explanatory. I tried bolding it but that doesn't appear to work in code blocks here; and I've been criticized before about linking to the MySQL documentation (would be the best explanation).

Comment: Linking and adding an explanation would be the best thing to do. It isn't hard to describe what you've done here.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting question :)
I think the problem is caused by the so called "referential integrity".
That means, that you are not able to delete a dataset, which primary key is used in another tables dataset as foreign key. If you could do this, some foreign keys of the table savebook would refer to a dataset in table books, that doesn't exist anymore.
So first you have to delete all datasets in savebook, where the bookid is the same one as of the book you want to delete and after that, you can delete this dataset from books. ;)

Comment: So at first you have to send "DELETE from savebooks WHERE bookid=1;" and after that DELETE FROM books WHERE bookid=1;

Answer (score 0):

You have applied constraints to the tables. You need to tell MySQL to delete referenced entries from "savebook" table if any entry is deleted from "book" table.

```
ALTER TABLE savebook ADD CONSTRAINT bkid_usid FOREIGN KEY (bookid) REFERENCES books (bookid) ON DELETE CASCADE
```